# Flask: how to link wtforms with jinja2-templates using bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, jinja2, flask-wtforms

it seems a stupid question but I do not really get the connection.

I use tghe latest bootstrap version ad have this template:

```
<div class="form-group"{% if form.name.errors %} error{% endif %}>
            <label for="name" class="col-md-2 control-label">Name:</label>
            <div class="col-md-10">
              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" placeholder="Enter your name here">
              {% for error in form.name.errors %}
                        <span class="help-inline">[{{ error }}]</span><br>
                    {% endfor %}
            </div>
          </div>
```

The field is rendered as desired but no matter what I enter there my form will raise the error, that this field is required.

Please let me know what I miss here - how do I link the field in the template to my form properly?

Answer (score 0):

The issue was that the "name" attribute was missing - only having the "id" is insufficient.